# Image not loading from res directory

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to load an image (*Path:* `project/res/myImage.png`) on my page (*Path:* `project/pages/myPage.xaml`) but when the application runs everything else is working fine but the image is not loaded.

I've checked that the image is properly added to the resources.
Also tried a couple of variations in the code e.g. writing `../` before 'myImage.png' but got no luck.

```
<Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                   Source="myImage.png"
                   IsVisible="True"/>
```

I'm expecting the image to be loaded in the backgroung of other labels, but the background is black (default color).

Comment: Did you load your images successfully?

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, read the tutorial on Xamarin.Forms page about images as there are many option but this one isn't one of them. I think this is most close to what you require, but read whole the page there and find what suits you the best: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#using-xaml

Answer (score 1):

When you put your image in the `Path: project/res/myImage.png`, it should be treated as  [embedded-images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images), and you can load them by:

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("yourprojectname.res.yourPictureNmae.jpg", typeof(EmbeddedImages).GetTypeInfo().Assembly) };
```

Or in Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource yourProjectName.res.yourPictureNmae.jpg}" />
```

To load images by using `<Image Source="myPicture.png"/>`, you should add the image files to each application project which referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code:

- **iOS**:

  Add image file to  `Asset Catalog Image Sets`
- **Android**

  Add image file to `Resources/drawable directory`
- **UWP**

  Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content.

Then you can load the image by:

```
<Image Source="myPicture.jpg" />
```

Or in code behind

```
var image = new Image { Source = "myPicture.jpg" };
```

For more information, you can read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images) that *Ivan Ičin* mentioned in his answer.